# Compare two tables and add a column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a relational database that I want to compare the differences of the data from two entries.  Each entry may vary only slightly, but there may be around 100,000 rows to between the two entries to compare.

I put all of the data that I want to compare from both database entries into two separate temporary tables, which excludes all of the primary and foreign keys that are set up as unique values (so, they would always be different... and return a result).

The way I do it now is:

```
    Select PrimaryStream, SecondaryStream, FirstFrame
    From #tempTable1
    UNION
    Select PrimaryStream, SecondaryStream, FirstFrame
    From #tempTable2
    EXCEPT
    Select PrimaryStream, SecondaryStream, FirstFrame
    From #tempTable1
    INTERSECT
    Select PrimaryStream, SecondaryStream, FirstFrame
    From #tempTable2
```

I get the results of the differences that I want, but I also want to add the "PrimaryStreamName" to these results, which is in #tempTable1 and #tempTable2, but I can't use them for comparison because they will always be different.

Each PrimaryStreamName will be the same in #tempTable1 and each PrimaryStreamName will be the same in #tempTable2, but #tempTable1.PrimaryStreamName != #tempTable2.PrimaryStreamName.

So, my goal is to add the PrimaryStreamName to the result.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: what dbms are you using?

Comment: Ok. Which column(s) uniquely identifies your records? Is PrimaryStreamName stored in both of your temporary tables? Some schema of the tables would help to understand the result.

Comment: @Lesya, there is no unique identifiers, or the entire row is a unique identifier.  If there is a unique identifier I will get a result, because that exact row is not included in both entities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, check the performance, but following query should give expected results:

```
Select PrimaryStream, SecondaryStream, FirstFrame, '1' PrimaryStreamName
From #tempTable1
UNION ALL
Select PrimaryStream, SecondaryStream, FirstFrame, '2' PrimaryStreamName
From #tempTable2    
EXCEPT
( 
    (
        Select PrimaryStream, SecondaryStream, FirstFrame, '1' PrimaryStreamName
        From #tempTable1
        INTERSECT
        Select PrimaryStream, SecondaryStream, FirstFrame, '1' PrimaryStreamName
        From #tempTable2    
    )
    UNION ALL
    (
        Select PrimaryStream, SecondaryStream, FirstFrame, '2' PrimaryStreamName
        From #tempTable1
        INTERSECT
        Select PrimaryStream, SecondaryStream, FirstFrame, '2' PrimaryStreamName
        From #tempTable2
    )
)
```

Note, that there's a trick: I perform `INTERSECT` two times (and I use `UNION ALL`, since it's faster than `UNION`), so the query operates on more rows during some operations.

Comment: that doesn't work.  It just returns everything in both tables, because the PrimaryStreamNames are different from #tempTable1 and #tempTable2.  If I would exclude PrimaryStreamNames it works like a champ, but I don't get PrimaryStreamNames in the result.

Comment: Are you sure? Using `PrimaryStreamName` pseudocolumn 4 times in the `EXCEPT` part of the query should give every possible row to be removed from the result. And then you'll get only different rows with `PrimaryStreamName` pseudocolumn informing about the source.

Comment: Sorry I had the pseudos as 1-2, 1,2.  Thanks, so much!  I pretty much blew the whole day on that before your help.  Thanks again!

Comment: I noticed that if one of the tables has more rows than the other table, I am not getting any of that information back as a difference.  Can you think of a way I can do that too?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand what information you don't get. Are there some rows missing that should be in the result? Can you clarify by giving some further explanation or example?

Comment: Hi BRU.  If #tempTable1 had 20 rows (with 5 of the rows being duplicates) and #tempTable2 had 15 rows (which all had a match in #tempTable1), I would not get any results returned from the above query.

Comment: If 5 rows are duplicate to some 5 of 15 that had a match in #tempTable2, then to me it's expected that they are not returned. I can think of some query modification if you need them to be returned.

Comment: Hey Bru, I'll just compare the counts too.  So, that will put this question to bed for me.  Thank you for all of your help!